# Does running a live wallpaper slow down your PC when gaming or is it no longoer being processed as not on screen?

Tags: memory

I have just downloaded wallpaper engine from steam and I have set the live wallpaper to highest quality and to run at 60 fps with 8x mmxa and according to task manager its using 22% of my 16gb ram?

Is this normal and  will it stop using the ram as soon as its not onscreen anymore when I start gaming?

my Rig is Alienware ALX 16gb standard Alienware ram 1600hz I-7 3930k overclocked to 3.8 ghz (water cooled) 2x GTX 780 sli with g-synch standard Alienware 1200w power source running an ASUS rog swift 27" 1440p 144ghz monitor. And I ALWAYS run at maximum resolution! and refresh rate.

Comment: The amount of RAM it uses is not really the salient point, it's the amount of CPU. The RAM will be paged if necessary. You need to check that it 'sleeps' when not in view.

Comment: according to task manager its using 1.2% cpu power that's good yes?

Comment: but will it still consume ram when I'm gaming and is not visable, or is it still running in the background?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it just a personal opinion, but I never understand purpose of wallpapers and especially live one. If you using computer, desktop's background will be covered with front end windows and it is the case to use computer. I can understand if it used as an eye candy in a shop, as a demo to attract buyers , but not when you use it, most of the time it simply covered by some running program. Computer is like a car, than more you loaded it than more gasoline  it ate and become slow. The same  things with CPU and RAM.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because, I've used live wallpapers in the past and every time a client opened up the wallpaper paused so it can reduce my ram and CPU usage. But having anything running in the background will slow your PC down a bit. I would like to say, that it uses a fare bit of memory though but I think your PC performance wont have a major effect with live wallpapers running.